# Command line syntax for multiple TestNG groups

Tags: java, maven, command-line, testng

I want to select among multiple TestNG groups from the command line in a Java Maven project. Here's an example:

```
@Test(groups = { "AAA, BBB, CCC" })
public class MobileAccountTest {

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        System.out.println("* MobileAccountTest.testA()");
    }
}
```

When I run this in the command line: `mvn clean test -Dgroups="AAA"`, Maven finds 0 tests to run. Same thing if I run `mvn clean test -Dgroups="BBB"`. But if I run `mvn clean test -Dgroups="CCC"`, it does find and run the test. Why does it only recognize the last group entry?
Based on a TestNG online book extract, I tried this in the java code: `@Test(groups = { "AAA.BBB.CCC" })`, and then on the command line: `mvn clean test -Dgroups="AAA.*"`, but that makes Maven throw an error: `Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.group.parse.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 10.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""`

So what is the proper command line syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your different groups in different quotations. For example:

@Test(groups = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" })